# How to compute, for each row, the "previous" mean of a group?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe who looks like this :

```
df = data.table(type=rep(x=LETTERS[1:2], each=4),year=list(2009,2010,2013,2016,2003,2005,2009,2015), outcome = list(1,2,1,4,3,1,5,3))

    type year outcome
1:    A 2009       1
2:    A 2010       2
3:    A 2013       1
4:    A 2016       4
5:    B 2003       3
6:    B 2005       1
7:    B 2009       5
8:    B 2015       3
```

What I would like to do is, for each row, compute the previous mean of the outcome grouped by type.
What I mean by "previous" is that for a row `r` of `type = A`, I want to compute the mean of all the rows `j` of `type=A` which has `j.year < r.year`.

In this case it will give :

```
       type year outcome previousMean
1:    A 2009       1            0
2:    A 2010       2            1
3:    A 2013       1          1.5
4:    A 2016       4         1.33
5:    B 2003       3            0
6:    B 2005       1            3
7:    B 2009       5            2
8:    B 2015       3            3
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For each 'type, we can loop over the sequence of rows, subset the 'outcome' based on the sequence, get the `mean`, `unlist`, concatenate with 0 and assign (`:=`) to create the 'previous Mean'

```
df[, previousMean := c(0,unlist(lapply(1:(.N-1), 
               function(i) mean(outcome[1:i])))), by = type]
```

---

Or another option is `cummean` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df[, previousMean := c(0,cummean(outcome)[-.N]), by = type]
```

#### data

```
df = data.table(type=rep(x=LETTERS[1:2], each=4),
                year=c(2009,2010,2013,2016,2003,2005,2009,2015), 
                outcome = c(1,2,1,4,3,1,5,3))
```